# How to take the inner product of a Schur Function and Skew-Schur function quickly

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

Consider the Hall-inner product of a Schur Function with a Skew-Schur function. Say for instance $\langle s_{(5,3,2,1)/(3,2,1)} , s_{(3,2)} \rangle$. What is a fast way to compute this?

Since $\langle s_{\lambda /\mu}, s_{\nu} \rangle = \langle s_{\lambda}, s_{\nu}s_{\mu} \rangle$, the $s_{\nu}s_{\mu}$ term could be expanded by using the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients, and then use the fact that the inner product is billinear along with the fact that the Schur functions are an orthonormal basis for the symmetric functions to get the answer. However, this seems pretty slow to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have since spoken with a professor about the problem of finding the inner product of Schur functions and apparently it is difficult in general and finding new ways to compute it is somewhat of an open problem.